# My mesh is deforming strangely when I move it in Pose Mode

Tags: mesh, rigging, armature, bones, vertices

I made a mesh of a bird and my rigging is almost done. However, the wings are giving me some trouble. Although I'm pretty sure I've weight painted them correctly, when I move the bone, it looks like a wet McDonald's French Fry. I'll attach some images so you can see what I mean.[image]

Comment: other bones than these ones must affect this part of your mesh, se remove the vertices from any vertex groups and paint in Weight Paint mode?

Comment: There are extensive tools to know which bones are affecting which vertices.  Perhaps you can find one of those videos  on the site which has the name that rhymes with noonoob.  I did see one 2-3 years go that had extensive explanations.  You should try to find a similar video.  Your current problems will be easily solvable at that point.  You go into weight paint mode and click on each vertex group to see if a vertex group lights up the defective area.  You can also look at the display to see how many groups are affecting a vertex.  The videos mentioned will explain this.

Comment: You should add a picture of the defective area in weight paint mode.  You can also delete your current work and assign automatic weights and have the joy of doing the work a second time.  Its best if you assume your weight painting has an error created by ... well ...

Comment: please share your file so that we can take a look: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 0):

More details would be helpful..
But I think that top bone some how got unchecked for deforming. Just check in bone section in edit mode.
If I am not wrong then It should work.